# Reference to a list of affine Cartan matrices

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I can find a list of affine Dynkin diagrams in some books but cannot find a list of affine Cartan matrices. We can write down affine Cartan matrices using affine Dynkin diagrams. But are there a list of affine Dynkin Cartan matrices in some book or paper? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a funny coincidence, I was just reading Macdonald's paper [Affine root systems and Dedekind's $\eta$-function](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=357528). The appendix has a really clear and detailed description of all the affine root systems. It doesn't explicitly list Cartan matrices, but I think you should be able to work them out easily enough from this data.